# after startIntentSenderForResult called, onActivityResult has wrong requestCode

Tags: android, google-drive-api, onactivityresult

this the code in my fragmnet. 
original requestCode is: 2

```
     GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleConnectionCallbacks())
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleonnectionFailedListener())
                .build();

            int a = 2;
            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                        .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                        .build(mGoogleApiClient);
            getActivity().startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, a, null, 0, 0, 0);
```

code in activity containing my fragment:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}
```

now requestCode is: 131074.
why i din't get requestCode = 2 ?

Comment: What is the intent you are trying to open? are you sure that it returns the error code that you send it?

Comment: thanks for the comment. i edited my question with more code.
its not about the error code.
it returns different request code from the one i sent.

Comment: The thing is that the intentSender tells the activity to do something specific, but you cannot know that the called activity will really return this result code(unless you checked it in the code/doc). It probably return a different hard coded result code like in many cases. You just need to use this result code. Do not forget that you do not control of the result code, the one that is in charge of it is the called Activity - OpenFileActivity